# React.js + OpenCV.js ReferenceError: cv is not defined

Tags: reactjs, opencv

I can't run opencv.js and react.js together because (I think) opencv.js is too big (7.8mb) for yarn to compile (I get max callstack error). Given that, I also can't load opencv.js in the index.html because it loads too slowly for React to pick it up, giving me `cv is not defined`.

Creating an onLoad="myfunc()" function gets me furthest, as I can set a var `loaded` to be true and wrap an if statement around the ReactDOMrender. But it doesn't ever pick up when the var changes to true and never renders.

I've tried the following:

1. Importing the `opencv.js` script right into my `index.js` where I'm testing this out. I get a Max callstack error. I'm guessing this is because opencv.js is around 8mb and the compiler doesn't like it?
2. I've tried to add `opencv.js` in the `public/index.html` file. I load it using `async` and add `/*global cv*/` to the top of my `index.js` file. I get the error cv is not defined.

```
import React from 'react';

/*global cv*/
var mytest = function() {
    var test = cv.Mat();
    console.log(test + ' if you see something before this, opencv loaded');
}
mytest();


function App() {
  return (
    <div>hello world</div>
)}

export default App;
```

and in the  of the index.html:

`<script async src="opencv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

This fails and says cv is not defined. I've also tried this with an `onLoad="whenOpenCvLoads()"` using this function to set a var to be true, and wrapping (what I believe to be) the first called function in react like this:

```
if(openCvIsReady === true){
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root')); 
    console.log(openCvIsReady + ' in react');
}
```

This evaluates to false and never runs when the variable eventually becomes true.

Comment: did you ever figure this out??